# If the PHP file is called from a symlink directory

Tags: php, path, symlink

I need to call a PHP file from a symlink directory. The PHP file can create files in an upper directory, for example it calls "newfiles". Like this:

```
websitedocroot/phpsymlinkdir/myphpfile.php
websitedocroot/newfiles/
```

How can I find out in the PHP file what is the symlink path on the server when it's called? Every times it's called from different domaim/website.

**UPDATED**

Comment: What do you mean by "path on the server" - the original path, the symlink path, or the current URL?

Comment: I need to find out the symlink path. For example: the real path is this: /var/www/core/myphpfile.php, and the symlink path, what I need is this: /var/www/domain/www.example.com/core/myphpfile.php

Comment: Try Goutam's suggestion below - I'm not sure whether it will give you the symlinked path but it might. Other than that, try `phpinfo()` and see whether the right path is in there in some variable.

Answer (score 0):

use `dirname(__FILE__)` to know the path of your file

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use `readlink()` for retrieving symlink path on the server.
get help from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readlink.php)